# BIOS for baremetal programs on x86

Tags: x86, bios, bare-metal

Is it a good idea to use the BIOS interrupts `INT10`? Or should I consider coreboot, UFEI or openFirmware? Are these compatible? What should I use to display to the screen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're mixing up a couple of entirely unrelated things here.

- Coreboot is an alternative to the PC BIOS which is not available for all motherboards, and which must be specifically installed by the user. It must always run a *payload*, which may be something like the Linux kernel, or an open-source PC BIOS such as SeaBIOS (at which point, it's largely indistinguishable from any other PC BIOS).
- UEFI is an alternative to the PC BIOS which is more advanced, but considerably harder to code for. It almost always contains compatibility routines for the standard PC BIOS.
- Open Firmware is a rough equivalent to the PC BIOS used on some other platforms, including PowerPC Macs and some Sun systems. It's never been used on an x86 system that I'm aware of, so it's almost certainly uninteresting to you.

If you are programming for a bare-metal x86 system, then interrupt 10h is probably the way to go. The next alternative to consider would be accessing the VGA hardware directly.

Comment: Thank you. But I am still not clear what I have mixed up. It looks like all these are alternatives for the original PC BIOS. Can I assume that using `int 10` shall not break across various bios?

I was also wondering at what point these BIOS begin to differ or outstrip PC BIOS.

Comment: Interrupt 10h will work on all PC BIOS systems — which is to say, everything you are likely to encounter.