# CPU device driver in Microsoft Windows

Tags: c, assembly, driver, cpu, bootable

If we consider the language C. It directly compiles the code in the processor instructions. So, it doesn't matter on which processor the program is executed. But if we consider assembly language, it's specific to the processor it is being executed on. So, according to this if we make a program in C, & make it a bootable. There should be no problem of the processor being used, & the program should run right away, And it also does run without any issues. Then why is it so, Microsoft Windows requires drivers to use a CPU ( You can check it device manager, where driver for the CPU being used is installed ). If a simple bootable program , can be written, compiled, & executed, without requiring a  driver. Then why is CPU driver installed in windows ?

Comment: While a interesting topic, I think this is off topic for this site. You may have better luck asking over on http://SuperUser.com. Please don't post on both sites, either delete this question or flag it for a moderator to be moved. Also one of your assumptions are wrong, C is compiled in to assembly, which is then compiled in to machine code. So C and assembly are the same thing, just you are skipping the first step.

Comment: No, I think that if reworded it could be appropriate. His question regards portability of code which is dependent on the assembly language and machine instructions. It is a programming question but does touch on a lot of different topics making it tricky to answer without writing a novel.

Comment: "It doesn't matter on which processor the program is executed" - yes it does!  You can't run a program compiled for ARM on an x86 (not directly, anyway).

Comment: Lol, I saw that comment change! He does have a misunderstanding but we can clear that up here.

Comment: There's nothing, I think should be reworded. It's exactly what I want to ask.

Comment: But you seem to be the only one who can understand the question. I'd start by separating the driver part - you seem to misunderstand the basic concept of compilation

Comment: I think the question is simply "why does Windows need CPU drivers?", right?  Nothing to do with compilation, etc. at all.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it has nothing to do with the compilation part, it's for better understanding.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, yes, but there are too many misconceptions on the way. The drivers part is relatively straightforward - you can't run privileged operations from user code, you need system code, but you're not writing the OS so you need some intermediate layer with special privileges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be able to do that, but only if your program doesn't do any I/O, i.e. not writting to the screen, no accessing the disk, etc.

To make a C program that actually does something it needs to perform some I/O (at least to send "Hello world" to a screen, or to a LED matrix, or to a serial port). I/O management can be either included in your program, as it's common with embedded devices, or available to it in form of shared libraries that your program loads and calls, managed by the OS.

That said, it's true that you can make, compile and run a simple program as boot program in many environments, provided that all the I/O routines it would need are included in the executable, and there's a tool chain that takes your C program and gives you a boot image executable for your desired platform.

On the other hand, Windows doesn't have a device driver in order for you to use the CPU. The device driver you have seen by the name "CPU" is for managing things like the IO APIC, to route interrupts; the Local APIC, to enable multicore processing, several features like virtualization, NX bit, etc. You see... it happens that the CPU has a few I/O devices inside it, so this device driver is for managing them.

Comment: I was just about to write something very similar.

Comment: Write your answer. It will surely provide another point of view, or complete things that I missed :)

Comment: According to my knowledge, if we use assembly language for Intel, and execute the program on an Intel machine, with a simple instruction to show some text on the display. It will work, without any need of a driver. Please Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: So, according to your answer , to display anything on the display, there should be I/O management included in the program. But exactly what information will the I/O manager contain?

Comment: If you display text on screen using int 10h you are actually using a driver, available through the BIOS. If you directly write to memory screen, at B800 segment, you are actually providing your own driver to handle the screen.

Comment: The information that the I/O manager contains is up to the maker of that I/O manager decides. It could be a series of functions like printf(), scanf(), which directly "talk" to the hardware. It can be a more general set of functions, like open(), close(), read(), write(), from which complex functions like printf() are built on, etc. There are various paradigms about how an I/O manager should contain and how should it behave. It's more a topic for OS design and ambedded design.

Comment: @Rahulsingh190: Basically yes, except for device I/O. And not even simple apps only. The whole code of any application is executed on the Cpu directly and needs no driver. The driver is for managing the CPU (as a piece of hardware) itself.

Comment: A program may not use a device driver at all for some devices. DOS programs used to behave this way, and provide their own set of functions to deal with the screen. Even some compilers let the user to choose how screen output should be performed: directly or through BIOS.

Comment: Going into the low level programming. And not using the drivers provided by the BIOS and instead creating own . should contain a very low programming. with the instruction given to CPU at which address the data is to be sent to displayed.

Answer (score 1):

The driver for the CPU is not needed for code execution, it is merely a kind of place holder for where the Cpu acts like a device. For instance to support power management or to read out core temperatures. There the OS needs a device to communicate with. The driver reserves the resources for that and offers the correspinding interface to higher levels.

For historical reasons, you need to specify the Cpu type for the assembler. For a C compiler, this is implicitly given by the platform you run it on. You usually need a different compiler for a different Cpu familly.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your question correctly you have misunderstood the compilation process for the C language and its purpose.

C [compiles](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Compiling) to [assembly language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_language) which is then converted into machine instructions. You need to read more about the [ISA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set) and [assembly language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_language) before you will understand that a compiled C program is in-fact processor specific (in reference to the type of processor e.g. x86 or ARM).

If you have compiled a C program for an ARM processor it won't work on an x86 processor. This is to do with the [ISA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set) of that particular processor. Things like virtual machines (e.g. Java) and interpreters (e.g. Python) are popular ways of improving the portability of your code.

Comment: If the C compiler is converting the code to assembly first, & then to machine instruction. Then exactly which assembly language is it converted to. Because we have many different assembly languages.

Comment: Depends on your compiler. GCC converts into the AT&T syntax assembly and you can see the output if you use the `-save-temps` option when compiling. http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html

Comment: So, is the core low level binary machine instruction same for the CPUs on the same platform as x32 bit. If we consider an AMD CPU with a mnemonic "pdo" which resembles the binary instruction 11001100 in the cpu.& this will load a hexadecimal value written after it in the memory. So the Intel CPU with the mvi mnemonic to load the hexadecimal value written after it also have the same binary machine instruction as 11001100 in the CPU.

Comment: CPU's with the same instruction set architecture have the same instruction set and hence you can use the same machine code. Those that don't have the same ISA cannot use the same machine code. Having the same assembly language doesn't mean you have the same instruction set.

Comment: So, it actually doesn't matters, if a C compiled program is first converted to amd assembly or Intel assembly till the arch is same. because the ISA will ultimately be the same.

Comment: And coming back to writing own drivers to display a text on the screen. When using 10h bios interrupt to display a text on the screen we are very near to machine instruction set. & in a computer there can't be anything more basic unit than the assembly language/ISA. & if we don't use the bios provided driver to display a text. What else can we use.

Comment: waiting for your reply

Comment: Sigh... Coming back? Where in your question or my answer was there a part about the BIOS interrupts and text display? There seem to be many digressions from the main topic that I suspect are a result of you taking a course in Computer Architecture and not understanding the material. Computer architecture is a large topic and I can't explain it here for you. In addition, please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask and open a separate question for the BIOS interrupt after reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13283084/bios-for-baremetal-programs-on-x86/13283163#13283163.

Comment: Yes, there was no part of BIOS interrupts in my question or your answer. But it was discussed in the comments of answer no. 1. I assumed you thoroughly read all the answers & their comments on the page.

Comment: Correct, I did read that answer and all the comments however I did not feel like I could add anything to the discussion so I did not join it. If you wish to ask me directly you are welcome to do that but I ask that we keep the BIOS parts in the comment section of answer no 1. To direct a comment in answer no 1 at me use the @ symbol before my username and it will show up in my activity feed, at which point I will gladly reply.